# AutoResetEvent in Windows Phone project - can't invoke handler

Tags: c#, windows-phone, autoresetevent

It's from Windows Phone project. I am trying to invoke few handlers, handler by handler to receive information about GPS / Reverse position. I wonder why it won't run correctly.

When I setup only 1 coordinate it's ok. I have message with Street etc. But when there is more coordinates my handler isn't invoke.

```
private async void SimulationResults()
        {
            done = new AutoResetEvent(true);
            Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
            geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;

            myCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(51.751985, 19.426515);


            if (myMap.Layers.Count() > 0) myMap.Layers.Clear();

            mySimulation = new List<SimulationItem>();
            mySimulation = Simulation.SimulationProcess(myCoordinate, 120); // Odległość

            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
            {
                done.WaitOne();
                if (mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Id == 1 | mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Id == -1)
                {
                    // Oczekiwanie, ponieważ obiekt jest zasygnalizowany od razu wejdziemy
                    // do sekcji krytycznej
                    AddMapLayer(mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate, Colors.Yellow, false);

                    myReverseGeocodeQuery_1 = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                    myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.GeoCoordinate = mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate;
                    myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1;
                    // Sekcja krytyczna
                    done.Reset(); // Hey I'm working, wait!
                    myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryAsync();

                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Skonczylem");
        }

        private void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
        {
            done.Set();
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                if (e.Result.Count > 0)
                {
                    MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
                    MessageBox.Show("Wykonano "+address.Street);

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you are blocking on your `AutoResetEvent` on the UI thread, but that's the same thread that the `ReverseGeocodeQuery` is trying to run on. Since it's blocked it can't run and it also can't invoke your callback.

A very quick fix that doesn't change your flow too much and assumes some sort of "on everything complete do X" requirement is below. I triggered the whole thing on a background thread with:

```
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            SimulationResults();
        })).Start();
```

Since all of the below is on a background thread I needed to add some `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` calls around anything that called into the UI thread, but this way the thread that is blocked is your background thread and not your UI thread.

```
    AutoResetEvent done;
    int remaining;

    private async void SimulationResults()
    {
        done = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;

        var myCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(51.751985, 19.426515);


        var mySimulation = new List<GeoCoordinate>()
        {
            new GeoCoordinate(51.751985, 19.426515),
            new GeoCoordinate(2, 2)
        };
        //mySimulation = Simulation.SimulationProcess(myCoordinate, 120); // Odległość

        remaining = mySimulation.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < mySimulation.Count; i++)
        {
            done.WaitOne();
            //if (mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Id == 1 | mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Id == -1)
            //{
                // Oczekiwanie, ponieważ obiekt jest zasygnalizowany od razu wejdziemy
                // do sekcji krytycznej
                //AddMapLayer(mySimulation.ElementAt(i).Coordinate, Colors.Yellow, false);

            var tempI = i;

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {

                var myReverseGeocodeQuery_1 = new ReverseGeocodeQuery();
                myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.GeoCoordinate = mySimulation.ElementAt(tempI);
                myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryCompleted += ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1;
                // Sekcja krytyczna
                done.Reset(); // Hey I'm working, wait!
                myReverseGeocodeQuery_1.QueryAsync();
            });

            //}
        }

    }

    private void ReverseGeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted_1(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
    {
        done.Set();

        remaining--;

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            if (e.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                MapAddress address = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wykonano " + address.Street);
                });

            }
        }

        if (remaining == 0)
        {
            // Do all done code
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Skonczylem");
            });
        }
    }
```

Alternatively you could also make this a proper async method that awaits on different events to progress.

Comment: My thanks for you. You save my day :) I was developing that part of my application since 1 week, I've tried to synchronize few events - it's main part of my project. Now I can move forward :)